# Unknown encryption type opening pdf file

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

When opening a pdf file with the iTextSharp library I get the following error:
Error: Unknown encryption type R = 6

The code is

```
 PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(file), null);
```

Many thanks, Jorge

Answer (score 8):

The `R` key in the standard security handler encryption dictionary denotes the revision of handler that shall be used to interpret this dictionary. The value of `6` is introduced in ISO32000-2 (PDF 2.0), it corresponds to AES encryption with a encryption key length of 256 bits.

PDF 2.0 is a new standard, and it's features are supported only by the new version of the library, iText7 for .NET, starting from 7.1.0.

Even though ISO32000-2 was released only a year ago, this encryption type was confirmed to be a part of the new standard years ago and can be met in documents created even earlier. E.g. Acrobat can encrypt with this revision starting from Acrobat X.

Comment: So if I add new version of the library iText7 for .Net starting from 7.1.0 resolves my issue? Thanks

Comment: Well, itext 7 is a complete rewrite, so you cannot simply update the library version and that's it.

Comment: @JorgeM See it as an opportunity: now you finally have an irrefutable argument to convince your boss to upgrade to iText 7.1.

Comment: iText7 for .NET is only compatible with Framework v 4.0? I'm using Framework v2.0. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are right. iText7 for .NET requires .NET Framework v4.0 or higher, or .NET Standard 1.6 or higher.

Comment: Strange I got PDFs in version 1.7 that also have 256 bits AES encryption and I get the same error. So is it only limited to PDF 2.0 ?

Comment: @Olivier Masseau `R` value of 6 is introduced in PDF 2.0 specification, so it's not entirely valid and safe to use it in PDF1.7 documents, however I can imagine that it still can be encountered.